# How to store Profile Views to show each user who's viewed their profile?

Tags: php, mysql

If we wanted to show each user which users of the opposite sex have viewed their profile, what would be the best way to keep track of all those views in MySQL?

Each user has a unique `userid` from the main `Users` table, which also stores their `sex`.

We would want to show each user the users that viewed them **in order of most recent view to oldest view**.

We would obviously not want to show the user themselves if they happened to view their own profile.

We would want to show guys only the girls that viewed them, and the girls only the guys that viewed them.

1. How would we setup the **table** of `ProfileViews` to do that?
2. What **indexes** would we use?
3. What would be the **query** we would need to show each user who has viewed them?

Answer (score 3):

This is a simple example that I will make for you, hope this helps.

**SQL:**

```
CREATE TABLE user
(
    user_id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    sex VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_USER PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;


CREATE TABLE profileview
(
    profileview_id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    visitor_user_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    date_time DATETIME NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_PROFILEVIEW PRIMARY KEY (profileview_id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

ALTER TABLE profileview
ADD FOREIGN KEY FK_PROFILEVIEW_USER(user_id) 
REFERENCES user (user_id);

ALTER TABLE profileview
ADD FOREIGN KEY FK_PROFILEVIEW_VISITOR(visitor_user_id) 
REFERENCES user (user_id);
```

**PHP:**

This is a simple example of the user profile page - **www.domain.com/profile.php?id=xxx**.
At this point you need to define two variables in session when the user logs into the site:
$_SESSION['user_id'] (int) / $_SESSION['user_logged'] (boolean)

```
<?php
if ($_GET && isset($_GET['id']){

    if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']){
       $profile_user_id = $_GET['id'];

       // the user that visits the profile has a session with his/her id on it.
       session_start();
       $visitor_user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    } else {
       // if visitor specified an id but there is no session, redirect to login.
       header("location: login.php");
    }
} else {
    // if no id passed redirect to index
    header("location: index.php");
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Your title</title>
</head>
<script src="scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//here you will store the visit with jquery.
$(document).ready(function(){
  // store the values from php.
  var profile_user_id = <?php echo $profile_user_id ?>;
  var visitor_user_id = <?php echo $visitor_user_id ?>;

  // here, the user information goes to the visit.php file.
  $.post('visit.php' { profile_user_id:profile_user_id, visitor_user_id:visitor_user_id } );
});
</script>
<body>
Here print user information from a SQL select or something of the id passed in the GET.
</body>
</html>
```

Now, the **visit.php** file to store data:

```
<?php
if ($_POST && isset($_POST['profile_user_id']) && isset($_POST['visitor_user_id'])) {

    session_start();

    // this will end the execution of the script if there is no session from user logged
    if ($_SESSION['user_logged'] != true) {
      exit();
    }

    // everything is ok, do the process:
    // functions.php contains your SQL connection, I suppose you know how to do it.
    include('../cgi-bin/functions.php');
    $link = dbconn();

    $profile_user_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['profile_user_id']);
    $visitor_user_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['visitor_user_id']); 

    // this will store the data in profileview including date and time if id's are not equal.
    if($profile_user_id != $visitor_user_id){
       $sql = "INSERT INTO profileview (user_id, visitor_user_id, date_time) VALUES ($profile_user_id, $visitor_user_id, NOW())";
       mysql_query($sql, $link);
    }
}
?>
```

**EXTRA:** if you don't know what **functions.php** do, here it is:

```
<?php

function dbconn() { 
if(!include_once('db.php')) { 
  die('Error include file.'); 
}

if (!$link = mysql_connect($db['hostname'],$db['username'],$db['password'])) { 
  die('Error connecting.'); 
}

if (!mysql_select_db($db['database'])) { 
  die('Error selecting.'); 
}

return $link; 
}
?>
```

The above file will need this file too: setup here your connection parameters to your db.

**db.php**

```
<?php
  $db = array( 
   'hostname' => 'localhost', 
   'username' => 'root', 
   'password' => 'mysql', 
   'database' => 'mydb' 
  );
?>
```

- I suggest you to put this in the `cgi-bin` folder of your hosting for better practices as you can see in `visit.php` file code.

Now, create another file called `visitors.php?id=xxx` and do a `select * from` of your profile views according to the `user_id`. At this point you will be able to:

- Get the `user_id` information and if it is men (for example)...

  - Select visitors by sex and do a rule to list only female visitors.
  - List visitors according to the time stored in profileview table.

Answer (score 1):

profileviews:

```
profile
userwhoviewed
timestamp
```

Index the profile column.

So when your user views the page, check if it's the profile owner, get the sex of the profile owner, check the sex of the viewer, if different, update the table with the viewer and the timestamp.

When querying the results, just select all rows matching the target profile, ordered by timestamp desc, and iterate to build your links back to those profiles.

I normally use INT data types in these fields (keeps the rows smaller and speeds up the lookups), then have a user table that generates those UID's as an auto_increment primary key.  That will hold your gender and preference fields, too, as well as any other ancillary user data, and makes it easier to change login names, if desired.

But you're leaving out your gay users. Better to just log them all and let the user filter based on their preferences. :)

Comment: If User1 viewed User2 two times at different times, should I record both views, or replace the old view with the latest view?  How would I do that?

Comment: depends on what you want, if you want to track the total number of views, then you'd add in another column `views` for example, then when you update the record, pull the current value and increment it, which should be trivial, since you're going to have to check the table anyhow to see if it's a new viewer or a return visit to determine whether you're doing an insert or an update.

Comment: But how would I deal with those multiple views?  For example, if User1 viewed User2 two times at different times, I wouldn't want User1 to show up two times under User2's "Who viewed me".  So how would I deal with that?

Comment: I'll rephrase my previous statement. 1) You set up another column, `views`, as an INT. 2) When the user views the profile, you check the  `users` table for a) user is not profile owner b) user is of desired sex 3) if you want to log this user, then check `profileviews` to see if this user has looked at this profile before, if no, then insert a new entry with a `views` value of 1, if yes, you take the current count of the `views` column for that record, increment it, and update that row of the table with the new value and current timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

```
UsersTable
UserID      Sex
1           Boy
2           Girl
3           Girl


UsersViewsTable
UserID      View    Unixtimestamp
1           2       342143243432
1           3       142143243432
2           3       242143243432
3           1       442143243432
```

When you visite the user profile, you'll use this :

```
IF CurrentUserSex != UserProfileSex
    INSERT INTO UsersViewsTable (UserID, View, Unixtimestamp) VALUES (CurrentUser, CurrentProfileUserID, time)
```

Now, you want to fetch this on a page to see last seen from opposite sex ?

```
SELECT * FROM UsersViewsTable LEFT JOIN UsersTable USING (UserID) WHERE Sex != CurrentUserSex GROUP BY View ORDER BY Unixtimestamp DESC
```

**EDIT :**

```
IF CurrentUserSex != UserProfileSex {
    $Res = SELECT CurrentProfileUserID FROM UsersViewsTable WHERE UserID = CurrentUserID AND View = UserProfileID LIMIT 1

    if($Res['Count'] == 1){
        // Exist
        UPDATE UsersViewsTable SET Unixtimestamp = time WHERE UserID = CurrentUserID AND View = UserProfileID LIMIT 1
    } else {
        // Doesnt exist
        INSERT INTO UsersViewsTable (UserID, View, Unixtimestamp) VALUES (CurrentUser, CurrentProfileUserID, time)
    }

}
```

Comment: How would you deal with duplicate views?  For example,  
if User1 viewed User2 two times at different times, should I record both views, or replace the old view with the latest view? How would I do that?

Comment: There ya go, see my edit... But, If I were you, What would I do is : First you create a "backup" of the row somewhere else (external DB, another table, even a log file for each user, doesn't matter) and then you update the row. Reason I see : you can track stuff, etc... BUT From this point, what you could do is add a field named let's say Count and do +1 each time and another field named LastVisit, so you track FirstVisit field (first time) and lastvisit update on last visit so you can see the first and last visit plus the count

Answer (score 0):

Just check n compare for each user profile page with the visitor id and profile id. If two are different store in a visit table with date and time and your required info. Before inserting just check the table row 
if prof id, vistor id already exists then update the time else just insert the data.

Thanks.